# Creation of new AzureAD application with powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I'm trying to create a new AzureAD application by using the Azure Active Directory Powershell 2.0 module, however after calling the New-
AzureADApplication I get a HTTP Bad requset with the following error.

```
+ New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "Umbraco-domea" -IdentifierUris $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADApplication], ApiException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.NewApplication
```

I found the following github issue with a bit of googling, however even by including the -IdentifierUris in my cmdlet call I still get the error.

```
New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $displayName -IdentifierUris $URIs -GroupMembershipClaims "SecurityGroup" -ReplyUrls @($Live",$Dev,"http://localhost:4198/")
```

Comment: Try including the -Debug flag, you might be able to see the exact error there.

Comment: Does not make a difference in the output of the error :/

Comment: Hmm, you could also try inspecting the traffic with Fiddler.

Comment: Here's an example I used: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/powerbi-powershell/blob/master/copyWorkspace.ps1 It's specifically for PowerBI, so may not directly apply but note that it uses a _native_ app because powershell is a client app, and also note that the redirect URI is `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`. This might be a complete red herring or it might give you somewhere else to look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script works for me, maybe you could test.

```
$displayName="shuitest"
$URIs="http://mynewapp.contoso.com"
$Live="https://localhost:8080"
$Dev="https://localhost:8081"
New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $displayName -IdentifierUris $URIs -GroupMembershipClaims "SecurityGroup" -ReplyUrls @($Live,$Dev,"http://localhost:4198/")
```

If you also get same error log, begin your script add `$DebugPreference="Continue"` to produce additional debugging information.

Comment: Not at work today, however I will check tomorrow. Thanks already Walter!

Comment: That did work for me. Issue was with how I was passing the URI. The official documentation says that the URI needs to be passed as a list however just passing the string caused it to work.